# Разрешение перегрузок для пачки параметров

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void foo(float&&) { std::cout << "f"; }
void foo(int&&)   { std::cout << "i"; }

template <typename... T>
void bar(T&&... x) {
    (foo(x), ...);
}

int main() {
    bar(.0f, 0);
}
```

Почему эта программа [выводит `if`](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEEgDMpAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcVyJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BXLaY9o4CdQ0ERRHRsXoK9Y3NOW0jvf0lZRIAlLaoXsTI7Bzm8aHI3lgA1Cbxbk4jxJish9gmGgCC1zcAbqh46Hv8qNS0qEwE5gBs/3mBwA7BY9iN0CAUMsCAcjoc3AczGYqOYzIcwSZgQARe5PF5vVAfUK/MwAslAvYgsEQqFoLywhEIpFmPBojEg3G3e4ETAsJIGXlwtwEACeSUYrEwADpZXsACqXPHPV5RBoQRVk/6y6V7VRArFWW5UqnUIkQfWkPY6%2BYY%2B5Yrl3W4kvYsJihCAG0H3E17NXECDSjRUK0aW3xI13HEcRa0TgAVl4fg4WlIqE4bms1nBy1WmCR8R4pAImhjiwA1iB4xp9JxJEnS2nOLwFCAayWUzHSHBYDBECBMKpqgySORKA1gAplIYOkIEKgAO7Jotofl0H4ZadhWhzxfJ1OrpJ0IbALjI0iH4/EADyDN3S84RcH1RuxEnzcCQ%2BQdXwyd4/EEEQxHYKQZEERQVHUTtSF0NoDCMFAs0sfQ8CiVtIEWVAki6BhWw4ABaCFDmxUxLGsMxUwUXM1mGAhfy3Wd5wfbheAIM51iLBdiCYJJHy7OMOETUh914dMOGwL8R2IPUAA4/nwv5JD2YBkGQPYz2lMw9ggTMyOQvZcEIEgCy4eZWNLeZFgQc4sDiT1SErataw4etSBYEBC00%2BNhMbMSWzbYsLO7PsICQZ9kCkscIAnKcZx3Jjl14S9BU3OL7xEi9UDXeg4h2QxT2rGtktiW9hASvjPxfN88N4cKf1CD8AOEURxFApqILURtdACeDjCQmxaFQ9D7KwnC8MIujiNIqxLAoltqJA2w6NCBj4r3Cq2MwDjeC4ni%2BNjBMG2gsSJOHIhpNUOSFKUvKjHU%2BMgyDbTdJmmwDPwc6TLMwLO0s0hrKYWzKAOlzeHczyzG8jK/NsAKOy0RYe37cLIooaLqtW9KKuSjcBEx8roOKuIHmQJIkgAfQeLgAE5yfieJydURTMuykq7wJp8v1fd8OFqr96r/MDmuAiRpHapROug3REl6xC9IGob4Ew7CMjwgB6WlpvIyiFto%2Bi0o51j2Iq3beJYkGhOhzhToiz6maUlgFBJvYqep6V6ee/qrUMz7NlM8zfqsmyhnsgTXPB4FpSh3yP1bdsLIrKsawE%2BIjtTGH4bLZyzDT0SP0zv6HliNJnEkIA%3D%3D%3D), а не `fi`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отличная задачка!

Вы забыли `forward`: `foo(std::forward<T>(x))`.

Без него, `x` - lvalue. Казалось бы, как код вообще компилируется? `float` преобразуется в `int`, и наоборот. Результат преобразования - rvalue, поэтому "противоположная" перегрузка как раз подходит.

Comment: Почему "противоположная" перегрузка лучше "родной"?)

Comment: @ueber Потому что родная вообще не подходит - ей нужно rvalue, а вы даете lvalue.